# Animation of alpha on UIView not working

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uiviewanimation, uistoryboardsegue

I'm making a custom segue that fades to black, swaps out the view controller and then fades back to transparent.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to do that.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.sourceViewController navigationController].view.frame.size.width, [self.sourceViewController navigationController].view.frame.size.height)];
    [overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.0]];
    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController].view addSubview:overlay];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn) animations:^{
      [overlay setAlpha:1.0];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
      [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn) animations:^{
        [overlay setAlpha:0.0];
      }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [overlay removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"Done!");
      }];
    }];

}
```

So, what I've done is add a UIView to the navigation controller that has a black background and an alpha of 0.  Then, I do an animation to change the alpha to 1, push the destination view controller onto the navigation controller, and then animate back to clear.  When I do this, nothing happens.  It just drops the destination view controller onto the navigation controller without any kind of animation.

Oddly, if I start with an alpha of 1 and animate to 0 and then back to 1, it works (but it isn't what I want).

I'm thinking that there's some optimization happening that excludes my clear UIView and so changing the transparency is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you do this?

```
...
[overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
[overlay setAlpha:0.0];
[[self.sourceViewController navigationController].view addSubview:overlay];
...
```

Comment: @JonA, you were animating the alpha on the view, not the background color. So, you need to set the background color to be opaque and start with the alpha on the view as transparent.

Comment: Oh, of course.  Must not be firing on all cylinders today.  Thank you for the followup.